# Merge Upsert without violating unique constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table that links users with skills:

```
DECLARE @tbl_UsersSkills TABLE (
    userId int NOT NULL,
    skillId int NOT NULL, 
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (userId, skillId)
);

INSERT INTO @tbl_UsersSkills 
    (userId, skillID) 
VALUES 
    (100, 1),(100,2),(100,3),(100,4),(200,1),(200,3),(200,4);
```

This provides the following result set when selecting all rows:

```
userId      skillId
----------- -----------
100         1
100         2
100         3
100         4
200         1
200         3
200         4
```

It has been decided that skill 1 is actually the same as skill 2, so we need to combine 1 & 2 together, leaving only 2.

I figured I could grab the skill 1 users, then delete them and re-insert them, but it seems like a fudge, and will increase the identity value (on the real table), and thought `MERGE` was a more glamorous option.

I need to get to this result set:

```
userId      skillId
----------- -----------
100         1 <-- removed because (100,2) exists already
100         2
100         3
100         4
200         1 <-- updated to be (200, 2)
200         3
200         4
```

Here's my attempt, but I get an error that the MERGE statement is modifying the same row multiple times.

> Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 The MERGE statement attempted to
>   UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a
>   target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot
>   UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine
>   the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row,
>   or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Can anyone perfect it?

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT userId, skillId FROM @tbl_UsersSkills WHERE (skillId IN (@s1, @s2)))
MERGE
    @tbl_UsersSkills tgt
USING 
    cte src
ON 
    (tgt.skillId = src.skillId)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (skillId) VALUES (@s2)   
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    tgt.skillId = @s2;
```

Comment: The MERGE Upsert can cause deadlocks. Might be better suited to use the standard two statement approach. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that the Merge statement had some bugs.  Not sure if I should be concerned, but I added the error I get for clarity.

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory here. You have more than one target row that matches a source row. That is because skillid is not unique. You need to make your ON clause match on only one row (maybe skillid, UserID?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is this is probably not a common occurence. So if it works, it works. I think instead of using MERGE, you can just update the UserId's with only skill 1(not skill 2) to skill 2. Then delete any rows with skill 1.

```
DECLARE @tbl_UsersSkills TABLE (
    userId int NOT NULL,
    skillId int NOT NULL, 
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (userId, skillId)
);

INSERT INTO @tbl_UsersSkills 
    (userId, skillID) 
VALUES 
    (100, 1),(100,2),(100,3),(100,4),(200,1),(200,3),(200,4);

UPDATE @tbl_UsersSkills
SET skillID = 2
WHERE skillID = 1
AND userId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM @tbl_UsersSkills WHERE skillId = 2)

DELETE 
FROM @tbl_UsersSkills
WHERE skillId = 1

SELECT *
FROM @tbl_UsersSkills
```

Results:

```
userId      skillId
----------- -----------
100         2
100         3
100         4
200         2
200         3
200         4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this two statement approach:

```
DELETE @tbl_UsersSkills
FROM @tbl_UsersSkills u1
WHERE u1.skillId = 1 and EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM @tbl_UsersSkills u2 WHERE u2.userId = u1.userId AND u2.skillId = 2)

UPDATE @tbl_UsersSkills
    SET skillId = 2
WHERE skillId = 1
```